# Summing values under a specific cell in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this, only is significantly larger. This is also part of a recurring issue I have to run monthly, so the values will always be changing:

```
| Name      | Category | Sales|
|-----------|----------|------|
| Product 1 | Sports   | 50   |
|   Friends |          | 30   |
|   Family  |          | 20   |
| Product 2 | Sports   | 50   |
|   Friends |          | 30   |
|   Family  |          | 20   |
| Product 3 | Politics | 50   |
|   Friends |          | 30   |
|   Family  |          | 20   |
```

Basically, I'd like to see the total number of sales, based on category and subgroup (friends/family). I feel I might've gotten closer by replacing the blank cells with the values above it, so the Category column is populated, but I'm not quite sure how to proceed from there.

Any ideas or areas for me to investigate?

Answer (score 1):

One of the hardest parts of using dataframes is having the data in the right format. The best way to represent this data for working in pandas may be something like this:

```
| product |   group | category | sales |
| :-------|--------:|----------|-------|
|    1    | friends | sports   | 30    |
|    1    |  family | sports   | 20    |
|    2    | friends | sports   | 30    |
| 2       | family  | sports   | 20    |
| 3       | friends | politics | 30    |
| 3       | family  | politics | 20    |
```

This places one item per row and eliminates replicating information.

After representing your data in this format, I would recommend using Pandas's [groupby function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

`df.groupby(['category', 'group']).sales.sum()` would give you the total number of sales for each `category`, `group` combination.

Answer (score 0):

your thought is close to the answer.
First of all, we need to fill up the blank `Category` cell for each row, and we can easily do that with keep the previous non-empty cell content.

There are two ways to do that.

### 1. Loop over all the rows with `apply()`

You can use the `apply()` function of dataframe to assign new values to a column.

```py
prev_category = None
def follow_previous_nonempty_row(category):
    global prev_category
    if category:
        prev_category = category
        return category
    else:
        return prev_category
    
df.Category = df.Category.apply(follow_previous_nonempty_row)
```

### 2. Fill up only the NA cell with `fillna()`

With the setting `ffill` or `pad` and along axis 0, `fillna()` will copy the previous row valid value into the NA cell.

```py
df.Category = df.Category.fillna(method='ffill')
```

And you can find out that all the empty category cells are filled with values.
Therefore, you can easily perform any conditioned summation now!

Comment: You may find the `df.fillna()` function easier than looping: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna

Comment: Great advice! Thanks @MichaelSilverstein !